# Make 2nd select menu dependent on the 1st select menu in jQuery UI Slectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have the following Select menus:

```
<form action="/search-our-collection" class="search-form" id="search-form" method="post">
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item">
      <label class="label">Make</label>
      <select name="make" id="make">
        <option value="America">America</option>
        <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
        <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="field-item">
      <label class="label"> Model </label>
      <select id="sub_groups">
        <option data-group="SHOW" value="0">-- Select --</option>
        <option data-group="America" value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
        <option data-group="America" value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
        <option data-group="America" value="Chile">Chile</option>
        <option data-group="Europe" value="Italy">Italy</option>
        <option data-group="Europe" value="France">France</option>
        <option data-group="Europe" value="Spain">Spain</option>
        <option data-group="Asia" value="China">China</option>
        <option data-group="Asia" value="Japan">Japan</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see there are 2 select menus , and i want them to be dependent on each other , i have a demo of how this works in a default HTML select [HERE](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/316/1/Grouped-select-boxes).
Now i want to do this in jQueryUI and i am not sure how to do this.

The first select menu has a data attribute has a value attribute eg `America` and the second select option has a attibute `data-group`, now when i select the option in the first select menu with a value of `America` , i want only the `options` in the 2nd select menu with the `data-group="America"` to be visible.

Now in by default the data-attribute are not copied from the HTML select to the jQueryUI select menu, so i tried the below code to do the same:

```
$.widget( "ui.selectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
      _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
         return $( '<li>' )
            .attr({
               'data-value': item.value ,
               'data-group':$(item.element).data('group')
             })
            .append(item.label)
            .appendTo( ul );
      } 
   });
```

But even the above code is not working. I have yet to code the part where the 2nd select box is dependent on the value selected from the first select box and i am not sure how should i go about doing this ? can somebody please guide me.

you can see the demo link [HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/DemoTest/jQuerySelect/).

Answer (score -1):

Please try this, it may help you:

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on('change',"select[name='make']",function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $('select#sub_groups > option').show();
        $('select#sub_groups > option:not([data-group="'+selectedValue+'"])').hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: its a jQuery UI question !